# R - greatest common divisor dplyr routine

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to find the greatest common divisor (gcd) for a set of durations: `dur`.

My data look like this

```
            actrec dur
1  c Personal Care 120
2      c Free Time  10
3      c Free Time  70
4      c Free Time  40
5         b Unpaid  10
6      c Free Time  20
7  c Personal Care  30
8      c Free Time  40
9      c Free Time  40
10     c Free Time  10
```

I am using the function `gcd` of the `schoolmath` library. 
I am looping through my data and store the values in the vector `v`. 
Finally, I use the `min` of `v` to find the gcd of my data.

```
library(schoolmath) 

l = length(dt$dur) 
v = array(0, l)

for(i in 2:l){
  v[i] = gcd(dt$dur[i], dt$dur[i-1]) 
}

minV = min(v[-1]) 
minV
```

Which gives `10`.

However, I have trouble translating this routine into `dplyr`.

I thought of something like (`lag` for loop).

```
dt %>% mutate(gcd(dur, lag(dur, 0)))
```

But it isn't working. And I am unsure how to insert `min`.

Any clue ?

Comment: Looks like the `gcd` is not vectorized.  Perhaps `dt %>% mutate(dur1 = lag(dur, default = dur[1])) %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(new1 = gcd(dur, dur1))`

Comment: Here's a vectorized version of gcd that could be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/a/21504113/3001626

Comment: thanks interesting

Comment: Using this function, you could do `dt %>% mutate(res = gcd(dur, lag(dur))) %>% summarise(Min = min(res, na.rm = TRUE))` which will be probably much faster than the  `schoolmath::gcd` one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `rowwise` to apply the `gcd` function on each row after taking the `lag` of 'dur, extract the 'new1' and get the `min`

```
dt %>%
   mutate(dur1 = lag(dur, default = dur[1])) %>% 
   rowwise() %>% 
   mutate(new1 = gcd(dur, dur1)) %>% 
  .$new1 %>% 
   tail(.,-1) %>% 
   min
#[1] 10
```

---

Or we create a `Vectorize`d function of 'gcd' and apply on the 'dur' column

```
 gcdV <- Vectorize(function(x,y) gcd(x, y))
 dt %>%
   mutate(new1 = gcdV(dur, lag(dur, default = dur[1])))
```

and get the `min` as in the above solution.

Comment: thank you - great answer. I am surprised actually that the code has to be so long.

Comment: @giacomoV  I was extracting the `min` as a single value.  If you want as a data.frame, it could be `dt %>% summarise(Min = min(gcdV(dur, lag(dur, default = dur[1]))[-1]))`